# HTML5 - validation

Tags: java, eclipse, html, css, tomcat7

Good morning.

I just got a free template from my friend, and everything worked fine except all .html files. Every html file has at least one issue, it's like if eclipse wouldnt recognize the HTML5 validation.

See an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>....</head>
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/27973852?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;api=1&amp;player_id=iframe334" height="240" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Error: Undefined attribute name (allowfullscreen).

Also, when I try to access one of my .html page, I get this error from Tomcat:

WARNING: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file  /about-me.jsp.  PTo resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.
Abr 26, 2014 12:29:24 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource

Ps: all the css3 files are working fine.

Comment: The attribute `allowfullscreen` isn't in any HTML specification so it will never be valid code. If you remove that attribute the tag will be valid and you'll still have the possibility to put the video in fullscreen mode:

`<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/27973852?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;api=1&amp;player_id=iframe334" height="240"></iframe>`

See it: [http://jsfiddle.net/K23cV/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/K23cV/1/)

Comment: Thanks. I'm not really good at front-end! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validator isn't up to date, then.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-iframe-allowfullscreen

However it should be just `allowfullscreen`, not `allowfullscreen="true"`.

https://validator.nu/ supports the `allowfullscreen` attribute.

Without the attribute, native fullscreen with `requestFullscreen()` will not work. Fullscreen from Flash or so might still work. I don't know what vimeo does but possibly it uses `<video>` + `requestFullscreen()` for some users or will do so in the future.

https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-requestfullscreen